# Is there an other way to include Jquery lib to communicate between Angular and this library?

Tags: jquery, angular, wrapper

I had to include a kind of library called RappidJS and a lot of Jquery files into an Angular 7 Project.
I used an homemade fonction to do it in my component :

```
ngOnInit() {
        this.loadScript('./app/assets/node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js');
        this.loadScript('./app/assets/node_modules/lodash/index.js');
        this.loadScript('./app/assets/node_modules/backbone/backbone.js');
        this.loadScript('./app/assets/build/rappid.min.js');
        this.loadScript('./app/assets/src/joint.ui.inspector.min.js');
        this.loadScript('./app/assets/src/joint.shapes.qad.js');
        this.loadScript('./app/assets/src/selection.js');
        this.loadScript('./app/assets/src/factory.js');
        this.loadScript('./app/assets/src/snippet.js');
        this.loadScript('./app/assets/src/app.js');
        this.loadScript('./app/assets/src/index.js');
}

public loadScript(url: string) {
    const body = <HTMLDivElement>document.body;
    const script = document.createElement('script');
    script.innerHTML = '';
    script.src = url;
    script.async = false;
    script.defer = true;
    body.appendChild(script);
}
```

The JS execute fine and my app shows up without any problem. However i need to communicate with some functions in "app.js" to retrieve some json and use it into my angular app.

In my component.html i have a toolbar :

```
  <div id="toolbar">
            <button class="btn btn-secondary add-question">Ajouter Question</button>
            <button class="btn btn-secondary add-answer">Ajouter Réponse</button>
            <button class="btn btn-secondary add-API">Ajouter module API</button>
            <button class="btn btn-success add-APIEX">Ajouter module Ping</button>
            <button class="btn send-json">Envoyer JSON</button>
            <button class="btn btn-secondary preview-dialog">Lancer dialogue</button>
            <button class="btn btn-secondary code-snippet">Code Snippet</button>
            <button class="btn btn-secondary clear">Effacer Tableau</button>
            <button class="btn btn-secondary load-example">Charger le JSON</button>
        </div>

and in app.js i have this : 

events: {
    'click #toolbar .add-question': 'addQuestion',
    'click #toolbar .add-API': 'addAPI',
    'click #toolbar .add-APIEX': 'addAPIEX',
    'click #toolbar .add-answer': 'addAnswer',
    'click #toolbar .send-json': 'sendJson',
    'click #toolbar .preview-dialog': 'previewDialog',
    'click #toolbar .code-snippet': 'showCodeSnippet',
    'click #toolbar .load-example': 'loadExample',
    'click #toolbar .clear': 'clear'
},
```

sendJson: function() {}

I really would like to know is there is a way to communicate between these ?

Thanks

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "communicate"?

Comment: I mean be able to retrieve information from app.js functions and use them into my angular component. And why not be able to send data to some functions of app.js too

Comment: You need to include js file which you can use globally, Right?

Comment: I tried to include them in my app.service.ts using import('......js') but it doesnt work because of problems of dependencies

Comment: The .JS files are "emulated" in the webpack. I can access to functions in my app.js but i can't access them and modify variables while they're running